# Разбиение массива на массивы python3

Tags: python, массивы

Мне надо из файла (в нем записаны строками данные) вытащить массивы, но они разной размерности. Построчно считываю их и записываю в один большой массив. Второй элемент этого массива - число 2n - кол-во элементов в массиве маленьком, который надо создать (сколько надо отделить от большого). После него идут сами элементы, а следующее кол-во записано только через 2n+1 - это m и так далее по всему большому массиву. Не могу в питоне сообразить реализацию данной задачи. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Пример файла  это первая строка-[500.0       106] потом с новой строки идут 106+106 элементов по 10 и 8 штук в строке , потом новая строка [ 1500.0        94] потом с новой строки опять 94+94 элемента и т.д Прикладываю пример файла. Я считываю программной все строки и записываю все в один массив большой s, и пытаюсь теперь начиная с s[2] начать записывать новый массив маленький из 106+106 элементов и т.д.[пример файла](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MJztLnUaVHMp-KrOJldbabLmgt6upKrE)

```py
fr=open('result.txt','r')
p=1
for line in fr.readlines():
    s=line.split()  #- это одна строка со всеми данными подряд
    break
while True:
    s[p]=int(s[p])
    l.append(s[p]) # массив всех кол-во каждого массива , как 106,94 и т.д
    ss=int(s[p])    
    p=s[(s[p]*2+3)] # сдвижка
```

а дальше я хотел зная кол-во элементов в массивах резать ту большую строку
Может быть  есть способ вообще по другому выделить нужное из файла?

Comment: С примера сразу нужно начинать. Какие входные данные, что должно получиться. В идеале - ваша попытка решения, чтобы указать на ошибку, а не решать за вас

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: MaxU, изменил!!